# Checked Non-Terminating Recursive Def?

Tags: formal-verification, lean

The following appears to type check in Lean 4:

```lean
def len_succ {a:Type} (h:a)(t:List a) : (h::t).length = t.length+1  :=
by
  induction t
  repeat simp

def pop {a:Type} (st:List a)(n:Nat)(r:n <= st.length) : List a :=
  match st with
  | h::t =>
      pop t (n-1) (by
        rw [Nat.sub_le_iff_le_add]
        rw [<- len_succ h t]
        exact r
  )
  | [] => []
```

I feel confused about this, given that `n-1` can underflow.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Does the fact that `-` for `Nat` in Lean 4 is actually truncated at `0` help here?

Comment: Besides the points about `-` on Nat, this definition is "obviously terminating" to lean because you only call yourself recursively on the tail of the list, so no matter what `n-1` computes it will only recurse as many times as the length of `st`.

Comment: Yeah, its an interesting example.  It is obviously terminating from a runtime perspective as you suggest.  However, trying to unroll this function as part of a proof elsewhere ... proved to be an endless rabbit hole :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the natural numbers in Lean, subtraction is "truncating", so in particular `0 - 1 = 0`.

Comment: Ok, well that answers the question.  I guess that was surprising to me!!

Comment: @redjamjar what would you expect it to do otherwise if it needs to output a `Nat`:)

Comment: Well, I understand the issue --- but mathematically speaking, it is at first surprising.  In other systems, `0 - 1` is simply reported as an error.  Anyway. is there a standard subtract method which takes a proposition?

Comment: You can always write a wrapper function that takes a proposition as an argument, discards it, and calls the "usual" subtraction function. Our experience has been that this is not particularly useful. It is better to have total functions with the best available "junk" values. Instead the *propositions* about these functions (necessarily) take these hypotheses.